# How to sort a directory listing sorted by size in browser?

Tags: url, browser, directory

1. How can I sort contents of a web directory in browse?
2. Why some directories have the option of sorting by clicking on column's headers and the others do not have?

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot or link to an example where you're seeing this?

Comment: http://mirror.iprimus.com.au/mediarss/iMovies---HD/

Answer (score 1):

By default, directory contents listings are generated by the webserver software directly, e.g. by Apache, IIS, etc.

Different webservers have their own way of presenting the information. The last time I checked, the latest versions of IIS and Apache still returned static HTML that remains unchanged for years.

It's possible you saw a custom implementation (such as a listing generated by a server-side script) or the browser's built-in WebDAV or FTP listing screen. IIRC Firefox's WebDAV and FTP listing page does let you sort the columns.

As for how you'd sort the list - that depends on how you're generating the list. If you're writing your own server-side program that generates the HTML then the easiest thing is to return the data in a `<table>` and use client-side scripting to sort columns. If you're relying on the server's listing page then there's nothing you can do unless you extend your server with a new listing generation module, which both IIS and Apache support.

Comment: thanks for your helpful info, it covers the secound question for sure, I think the answer of my first question is no, isn't it?